# How should config file for react-native-svg-transforme be after RN 0.72.0?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

My previous metro.config.js is:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

And After upgrade looks like this:

```
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

I tried like this as a resolver, but I got an error:

```
resolver: {
  assetExts: defaultAssetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
  sourceExts: [...defaultSourceExts, "svg"],
}
```

how exactly should I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found this solution.

```
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const defaultSourceExts = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults').sourceExts;
const defaultAssetExts = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults').assetExts;
/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: true,
            },
        }),
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: defaultAssetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
        sourceExts: [...defaultSourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the installation guide from `react-native-svg-transformer` should the new config (for react-native 0.72.1 or newer) look like this:

```
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
  }
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);
```

Link to guide: https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer#for-react-native-v0721-or-newer

Comment: Hey Thanks, yeah that’s correct as well

Answer (score 0):

@Letty answer is correct. The full config for yarn workspaces (monorepo) is as follow:

```
    const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const path = require("path");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
  },
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared')
  ],
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```